# Accessing App Service From Traffic Manager - Error

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

**Description**

I have configured traffic manager with Following Configuration

Route Method: Performance

Path : /

End Points:

Target Resource Type : App Service

Target Resource : < Pointing To App Service >

**Issue:**

When I access App service from its URI; works fine. but when I use Traffic Manager Uri I get below error:

***You do not have permission to view this directory or page.***

Answer (score 1):

The azure traffic manager is a DNS based load balancer, if you ensure the web app is working fine, I would like to suggest verifying the followings:

- Ensure you have [configured performance routing method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-configure-performance-routing-method#to-configure-performance-routing-method). Select the appropriate **Protocol**, specify the **Port** number and specify a valid **Path**.
- Check if the endpoint **monitor status** is `online` on the Traffic Manager UI. If the health of your Traffic Manager displays a **Degraded** status, then the status of one or more endpoints may be **Degraded**. You could use Fiddler, Curl, Wget tools to show the HTTP status code return from the probe URL. You could understand the TM probes and troubleshooting a probe failure [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-troubleshooting-degraded#understanding-traffic-manager-probes).
- DNS issue. Check if the endpoint alias could be resolved correctly via your local DNS resolver. For example, run `nslookup` TM URL in CMD.
  [image]

Let me know if this works or show more information for further help.